# Spurious NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, nosuchmethoderror

Been getting a NoSuchMethodError on one of our classes on a simple getter method.  The odd thing is that we can debug the code and see the error occur in the debugger (by stepping over the relevant line), however we can also use the IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) to see the method does exist.

Doing `xxxx.getYYY()` evaluates fine through the IDE expression evaluator.  And going `xxxx.getClass().getMethods()` we can see the `getYYY()` method in the list.  We have tried cleaning out all the built files, IDE output directories, IDE caches, rebooting etc and nothing seems to help.

I would understand a NoSuchMethodError would be happening if we had compiled against something but then a different Jar/class was being found at runtime.  But that doesn't explain to me why, at runtime while debugging to the line in question, we can see the method is there, but stepping over the line throws the Exception.

Tried reproducing on another machine but it does not reproduce.

Does anyone have any insight into what could be happening here?

Comment: do you have your own classloader hierarchy?

Comment: Could you edit the question and add a (complete) stacktrace?

Comment: What does that line/method do, and are you sure that it isn't that method that throws the NoSuchMethodError?

Comment: Can you give more information on your project setup? Do you run your app via IntelliJ or from the command line?

Comment: @Suraj, no just the standard classloader.  Just using basic Spring as a container with no clever stuff.

Comment: @Kaj, the exception indicates the exact method with signature so it's pretty clear which method is causing the problem

Comment: @Jens, on the machine in question we have run it through IntelliJ and it fails AND run our ant build and run it from the command line, same issue.  Checking exactly the same code out of source control onto another machine works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you are not running the same versions of code in IntelliJ as what you are editing. I get this problem often with lots of maven projects open at once with different versions in dependencies to what I am editing. IntelliJ can get confused (or I get confused as to which version I am actually running)

Comment: Yes that was my first thought but that doesn't explain the ability to reflectively "see" the method at runtime.

Comment: The method could be subtly different e.g. the return type might be different.  For the JVM, all the parameters and return type matter.

Comment: @Peter.  That's interesting.  Does the caller have full information about the calling method including the parameter types and return type?  I was under the impression the JVM resolved at runtime and would throw a NoSuchMethodError if the parameter values couldn't be coerced to a target method?

Comment: @Mike Q, that is what the compiler does.  If you change return type from `long` to `int`, you have to recompile the callers even though you wouldn't need to change the code.

Comment: @Peter, I think you were right with the return type.  We changed it to return Integer rather than int at some point and I think an old jar was being picked up.  Very hard to spot in the debugger this slight difference.

Comment: Agreed, since Java doesn't use the return type as part of the signature and Class.getMethod(Class[]) doesn't either, its easy to forgot the JVM does.

Comment: You might find this article interesting. It shows how you can overload by return types in Java. http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2011/02/with-generics-return-type-is-part-of.html

Answer (score 0):

NoSuchMethodError - This mostly occurs at runtime. I came across this error, the reason was incompatible versions of asm and cglib libraries in my classpath.

The asm and cglib libraries are used by many frameworks like hibernate, spring, hadoop for runtime byte code manipulation.

Classloader always refers to the first version of the jar on the classpath.